# How can I initialize datatable in jQuery to only search in odd rows and not even rows?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am quite new to javascript and jQuery and all of this, but i have a datatable that I only need to search the info in the odd rows and I cannot quite figure how to do it. The rows that are even are hidden unless you press on the row on top of it.

This is the jQuery init for the datatable:

```
$('#row-select').DataTable( {
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every( function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        } );

                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    } );
                } );
            }
        } );
```

Do you have any idea how could i fix it?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/data() shows you how to loop through the data, using `i` from `(row, i)` and check if even then skip.

Comment: An alternative approach could be to use [child records](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), rather than hiding even rows. (But I don't know if that would be compatible with the overall way your table is used.)